# Como atualizar a versão do app na Google PlayStore?

Tags: android

Depois de publicada a versão 1.0 do meu aplicativo, e eu com uma nova versão do mesmo projeto (2.0) e quiser atualizar. Como faço para enviar? Eu preciso da keystore apenas? O novo apk tem que ficar junto da key anterior na hora de selecionar?

Comment: Sim, você envia o apk com a mesma key e nome, basta mudar a versão para maior no manifest. Achei uma documentação oficial da google que explica o processo detalhadamente, mas está em inglês. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en **NOTA:** Não sei se é verdade ou se isso ainda ocorre porque a fonte que li é meio antiga (outubro de 2013), mas acredito que depois de lançar o update demora em media 24hrs para o update aparecer na play store, então se o update nao aparecer, espere umas 36hrs(fica a seu criterio) para se garantir ;)

Comment: Comigo tem levado cerca de 2 horas para a atualização aparecer na play store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só muda o manifest.xml nas tags

```
android:versionCode="1"  
android:versionName="1.0"
```

Nesse link explica qual a diferença nas tags 
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html

Em geral, demora duas horas para ser a atualização disponível

Comment: No link que tu passou está escrito: android:versionCode — **An integer** value that represents the version of the application code, relative to other versions. 
Ou seja, um valor inteiro, e na sua resposta você colocou `1` e `1.00` que além do segundo não ser considerado um inteiro mesmo se aceitasse floats, seriam a mesma coisa. O certo seria `1`, `2`, `3` e assim por diante.

Comment: Strokes, o `versionCode` tem que ser inteiro e o Google usa como o versionamento (progressivo), o `versionName` pode ser decimal e não tem efeito pro Google, apenas visual para os usuários (você pode ter o mesmo `versionName` para vários `versionCode` diferentes). E Além disso, se estiver usando o `Gradle`, tem que reforçar esses valores no `build.gradle` porque ele sobreescreve!

Answer (score 1):

você muda no manifestações e coloca

```
android:versionCode="n+1"
android:versionName="n.0.1"
```

e depois gerar o apk com o keystore que você usou na primeira vez. o versionCode no manifestações tem de ser sempre um inteiro maior do que o que você usou na versão passada por isso coloquei o n+1 onde o n seria a sua versão anterior. Só assim o playstore reconhecera como update ao seu aplicativo. O versionName é o numero que você quer que apareça para o usuário pode ser qualquer numero.